# Почему метод .append() не добавляет полностью идентичные элементы в DOM-дерево

Tags: javascript

Всем привет! Практикуясь с ванильным JS (игра "Найди пару") столкнулся с проблемой: в DOM-дерево не добавляются одинаковые элементы li из массива tileList через .append() (точнее, добавляется лишь один элемент, а второй не появляется как узел).

```js
  const createTileList = tilesQuantity => {
      const tileList = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < tilesQuantity / 2; i++) {
          const tile = document.createElement('button');
          // ...
          tileList.push(tile);
      }
      return tileList.flatMap(i => [i, i]).sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
  };

// ...

    const createBoard = tileList => {
        const board = document.createElement('ul');
        board.style.gridGap = '10px';
        board.style.height = '500px';
        board.style.width = '100%';
        board.style.padding = '20px';
        board.style.display = 'grid';
        board.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${Math.sqrt(amountOfTiles)}, 1fr)`;
        board.style.gridTemplateRows = `repeat(${Math.sqrt(amountOfTiles)}, 1fr)`;
        board.style.borderRadius = '20px';
        board.style.boxShadow = 'inset 0 0 20px #808080';
        board.style.listStyle = 'none';

        for (let i in tileList) {
            const li = document.createElement('li');
            li.append(tileList[i]);
            board.append(li);
        }

        return board;
    };
```

[image: Результат кода]

Сразу отмечу, я осознаю, что добавление стилей лучше производить в файлах-стилей, просто таким образом пытаюсь закрепить как можно больше знаний в языке.

Comment: [как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: какой именно append не работает?

Comment: В функции createBoard.

Comment: @fussygeekey, этот код работает.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> tileList.flatMap(i => [i, i])
> ```

Каждый элемент может находиться в dom-дереве только в одном месте. Если нужны две, то надо его клонировать:

```
tileList.flatMap(i => [i, i.clone(true)])
```

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка в использовании одного и того-же элемента для одинаковых карточек, в результате чего повторное добавление элемента новому родителю "отвязывает" его от предыдущего родителя.
Дублирование у вас происходит в этом месте `tileList.flatMap(i => [i, i])`

```js
  const createTileList = tilesQuantity => {
      const tileList = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < tilesQuantity / 2; i++) {
          const tile = document.createElement('button');
          // ...
          tileList.push(tile);
      }
      return tileList.flatMap(i => [i, i]).sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
  };
```

На скорую руку можно исправить код клонированием элементов, вот только при клонировании обработчики событий теряются, поэтому обработчик выносим в отдельную функцию и подключаем его так-же к копии (`fletmap` разумеется удаляем)

```js
(() => {
  const getRandomColor = () => {
    let red = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)
    let green = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)
    let blue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)

    return `rgb(${red}, ${green}, ${blue})`
  }

  let amountOfTiles = 16
  let choosenTile = null
  let isSearching = false
  let openedTiles = 0
  let steps = 0

  const createTileList = tilesQuantity => {
    const tileList = []

    for (let i = 0; i < tilesQuantity / 2; i++) {
      const tile = document.createElement('button')
      tile.style.height = '100%'
      tile.style.width = '100%'
      tile.style.borderRadius = '10px'
      tile.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent'
      tile.style.border = '1px solid #808080'
      tile.style.transition = '0.3s'
      tile.style.cursor = 'pointer'
      tile.setAttribute('data-color', getRandomColor())
      tile.setAttribute('data-is-opened', false)
      

      // изменение №1: выделяем обработчик кликов
      const clickHandler = e => {
        let tile = e.target

        if (tile.getAttribute('data-is-opened')) {
          steps++
          tile.style.backgroundColor = tile.getAttribute('data-color')
          tile.setAttribute('data-is-opened', true)
        }

        setTimeout(() => {
          if (isSearching) {
            isSearching = false

            if (tile.getAttribute('data-color') === choosenTile.getAttribute('data-color')) {
              openedTiles += 2

              if (openedTiles === amountOfTiles) {
                alert(`You won! Quantity of steps: ${steps}. `)
              }
            }
            else {
              tile.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent'
              tile.setAttribute('data-is-opened', false)
              choosenTile.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent'
              choosenTile.setAttribute('data-is-opened', false)
            }
          }
          else {
            choosenTile = tile
            isSearching = true
          }
        }, 500)
      }
      
      // изменение №2: подключение обработчика к 1-му экземпляру 
      tile.addEventListener('click', clickHandler)
      tileList.push(tile)

      // изменение №3: клонируем экземпляр карточки
      // (каждый клон может иметь своего родителя)
      const clone = tile.cloneNode(true)
      // изменение №4: подключение обработчика ко 2-му экземпляру
      clone.addEventListener('click', clickHandler)
      tileList.push(clone)
    }

    // изменение №5: удаляем старый метод удвоения карточек
    // flatMap(i => [i, i]) лишь удваивал ссылки на одну карточку
    return tileList.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5)
  }

  const createBoard = tileList => {
    const board = document.createElement('ul')
    board.style.gridGap = '10px'
    board.style.height = '500px'
    board.style.width = '100%'
    board.style.padding = '20px'
    board.style.display = 'grid'
    board.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${Math.sqrt(amountOfTiles)}, 1fr)`
    board.style.gridTemplateRows = `repeat(${Math.sqrt(amountOfTiles)}, 1fr)`
    board.style.borderRadius = '20px'
    board.style.boxShadow = 'inset 0 0 20px #808080'
    board.style.listStyle = 'none'

    for (let i in tileList) {
      const li = document.createElement('li')
      li.append(tileList[i])
      board.append(li)
    }

    return board
  }

  const createTileQuantitySelector = () => {
    const selector = document.createElement('form')
    selector.style.height = '40px'
    selector.style.width = '100%'
    selector.style.marginBottom = '20px'
    selector.style.padding = '5px 20px'
    selector.style.display = 'flex'
    selector.style.justifyContent = 'space-between'
    selector.style.borderRadius = '20px'
    selector.style.overflow = 'hidden'
    selector.style.boxShadow = 'inset 0 0 20px #808080'

    const input = document.createElement('input')
    input.style.display = 'none'
    input.setAttribute('id', 'value-container')
    input.setAttribute('type', 'number')
    input.setAttribute('min', 4)
    input.setAttribute('max', 100)
    input.setAttribute('value', Math.sqrt(amountOfTiles))

    const label = document.createElement('label')
    label.style.height = '100%'
    label.style.width = 'calc(50% - 5px)'
    label.style.display = 'flex'
    label.style.justifyContent = 'space-between'
    label.style.alignItems = 'center'
    label.style.borderRadius = '15px'
    label.style.backgroundColor = '#FFFFFF'
    label.style.boxShadow = '0 0 10px #808080'
    label.setAttribute('for', 'value-selector')

    const labelRightButton = document.createElement('button')
    labelRightButton.style.height = '100%'
    labelRightButton.style.width = '30px'
    labelRightButton.style.fontSize = '20px'
    labelRightButton.style.color = '#808080'
    labelRightButton.style.border = 'none'
    labelRightButton.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent'
    labelRightButton.style.borderRadius = '50%'
    labelRightButton.style.cursor = 'pointer'
    labelRightButton.style.transition = '03.s'
    labelRightButton.textContent = '>'

    const labelLeftButton = document.createElement('button')
    labelLeftButton.style.height = '100%'
    labelLeftButton.style.width = '26px'
    labelLeftButton.style.fontSize = '20px'
    labelLeftButton.style.color = '#808080'
    labelLeftButton.style.border = 'none'
    labelLeftButton.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent'
    labelLeftButton.style.borderRadius = '50%'
    labelLeftButton.style.cursor = 'pointer'
    labelLeftButton.textContent = '<'

    const labelTextContent = document.createElement('div')
    labelTextContent.style.fontSize = '16px'
    labelTextContent.style.color = '#808080'
    labelTextContent.textContent = Math.pow(input.value, 2)

    label.append(labelLeftButton, labelTextContent, labelRightButton)

    const button = document.createElement('button')
    button.style.fontSize = '16px'
    button.style.height = '100%'
    button.style.width = 'calc(50% - 5px)'
    button.style.padding = '5px 10px'
    button.style.borderRadius = '15px'
    button.style.border = 'none'
    button.style.backgroundColor = '#FFFFFF'
    button.style.color = '#808080'
    button.style.boxShadow = '0 0 10px #808080'
    button.style.cursor = 'pointer'
    button.textContent = 'Set board'

    selector.append(input, label, button)

    return {
      selector,
      input,
      labelRightButton,
      labelLeftButton,
      labelTextContent,
      button
    }
  }

  const createApp = container => {
    let selector = createTileQuantitySelector()
    let board = createBoard(createTileList(amountOfTiles))
    container.append(selector.selector)
    container.append(board)

    selector.labelLeftButton.addEventListener('click', e => {
      e.preventDefault()

      if (Math.pow(selector.input.value, 2) <= Number(selector.input.getAttribute('min'))) {
        return
      }

      selector.input.value -= 2
      selector.labelTextContent.textContent = Math.pow(selector.input.value, 2)
    })
    selector.labelRightButton.addEventListener('click', e => {
      e.preventDefault()

      if (Math.pow(selector.input.value, 2) >= Number(selector.input.getAttribute('max'))) {
        return
      }

      // A more pretty implementation is required
      selector.input.value = +selector.input.value + Number(2)
      selector.labelTextContent.textContent = Math.pow(selector.input.value, 2)
    })
    selector.button.addEventListener('click', e => {
      e.preventDefault()

      container.removeChild(board)
      amountOfTiles = Math.pow(selector.input.value, 2)
      board = createBoard(createTileList(amountOfTiles))
      container.append(board)
    })
  }

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    createApp(document.getElementById('root'))
  })
})()
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Я добавил комментарии в коде

Comment: Сойдет и галочка...

Comment: Это не мой вопрос))

Comment: Пойду просплюсь...